# how to update the url using ajax pagination in cakephp 2?

Tags: jquery, pagination, cakephp-2.3

Good morning,

I created a pagination via ajax using cakephp2.3, it is working properly. The problem is that the page number is not being updated in the url.

He is getting this way:

```
  / Localhost/cakephp-2.3.4/Anuncios/inicio /
```

And hoped that appeared to page / type, more or less, if I click on page 7, url must be:

```
  / Localhost/cakephp-2.3.4/Anuncios/inicio/page: 7
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?
I searched but did not find any material that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use history.pushState

Set your JS links for sorting and paging, for example:

```
if (history && history.pushState) {
        $('.yourTable th a, .paginationBar .controles a').on('click', function () {
            $.getScript(this.href);
            history.pushState(null, document.title, this.href);
            return false;
        })
        $(window).bind("popstate", function () {
            $.getScript(location.href);
        });
    } // history
```